# Ehcache JGroups Tcp replication error:dropped message from xxx(not in xmit_table)

Tags: java, replication, ehcache, jgroups

```
Used jar version:
ehcache-core:2.4.2 
ehcache-jgroupsreplication:1.4(exclusion ehcache-core)
```

I have two servers, one is 192.168.6.84 and another is 192.168.6.83,
and my configuration is:

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory propertySeparator="::" 
 properties="connect=TCP(bind_addr=192.168.6.84;bind_port=7800): 
TCPPING(initial_hosts=192.168.6.83[7800],192.168.6.84[7800];port_range=10;
   timeout=3000; num_initial_members=2): 
VERIFY_SUSPECT(timeout=1500): 
pbcast.NAKACK(use_mcast_xmit=false;gc_lag=100;retransmit_timeout=3000;
   discard_delivered_msgs=false): 
pbcast.GMS(join_timeout=5000;print_local_addr=false)" class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"/>
```

And another configuration only change the ip address.
And in my test code, I do only one thing:

- one server A always put element in cache per 2 seconds,
- another server B always get cache's size per 2 seconds

B's cache size is always 0 and it warns:

```
NAKACK.java:794 -- xxxx(B's computer name):dropped message from xxxx(A's computer name) (not in xmit_table),keys are xxxxx,view =[xxxx|0]
```

Is it my configuration error?

Comment: And sometimes there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

First off, your configuration looks odd: you're missing UNICAST, any failure detection protocol (FD_ALL, FD_SOCK), and STABLE. Absence of the latter means you'll eventually run out of memory as messages to the entire cluster are not purged!

The error you're seeing means that the cluster has *not* formed.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Where can I get the standard tcp.xml based on the version of JGroups?I have checked the jgroups official website,but did not find.

Comment: There are a few sample configs shipped with JGroups (in the JAR), or check out https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/tree/master/conf, e.g. `tcp.xml`, and modify it according to your needs (e.g. `bind_addr`).